# Bypass in-browser authentication to connect to internet

Tags: raspbian, networking

How can I connect my Pi to the internet on start-up if I need a in-browser authentication from my ISP.

I can connect to my router by providing the SSID and PSK in `/etc/network/interfaces` file or in the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_suppicant.conf` file and including it to the interfaces file.

However to get complete access to the network (internet) I need to open a browser which redirects to my ISP's homepage and I need to provide my username and password, only then I get access to the internet.

How do I do that in the pi? But it should get internet access at start-up, no human intervention. Where do I insert the username and password provided by my ISP and the url?

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663490/python-how-do-you-login-to-a-page-and-view-the-resulting-page-in-a-browser) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560959/using-python-to-sign-into-website-fill-in-a-form-then-sign-out). They're both questions on Stack Overflow that talk about using Python (probably your best bet for a simple solution) to submit a form.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2 part question.

1) How to login from the command prompt. You can use many languages... I would opt for bash/curl:
https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request
There may be complications with this step requiring multiple requests but testing and the brower console are the only way to know if extra steps are needed and what they would be.

2) how to run a script on boot or better network connection:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/258580/how-to-run-a-script-depending-on-internet-connection

Answer (score -1):

I do recommend you to use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se) from a command-line in conjunction with Perl [UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/libwww-perl-6.15/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm). We can develop a solution together if you wish